# Bounds on probability of sample mean in a small neighborhood rather than the tail

Tags: probability, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

Say we have i.i.d random variables $x_i$ whose mean and variance are $1$. Then the sample $s_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ has mean $1$ and variance $\frac{1}{n}$. If we are given a small enough positive $\epsilon$, e.g., $\epsilon\in(0,0.5)$, what bound can we get for $P(0<s_n<\epsilon)$ for all $n$?

For example, if we consider the Chebyshev inequality, we have
\begin{align}
P(0<s_n<\epsilon)&\leq P(|s_n-1|\geq 1-\epsilon)\\
&=P(|s_n-1|\geq \sqrt{n}(1-\epsilon)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\\
&\leq\frac{1}{n(1-\epsilon)^2}
\end{align}
This bound is rather loose because of the first inequality. I also checked other inequalities, like Hoeffding's, yet they are all bounds for the form of $P(|s_n-1|\geq a)$. If we think about $x\sim\mathcal{N}(1,1)$, then $s_n\sim\mathcal{N}(1,\frac{1}{n})$. Thus,$$P(0<s_n<\epsilon)<\epsilon\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{n(1-\epsilon)^2}{2}\right)<t_0\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\exp(n)}\epsilon,$$ where $t_0$ is the constant coefficient.

I wonder what bounds, similar to the above that decreases to $0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, can be obtained? Perhaps some assumptions shall be placed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use the Berry-Esseen theorem to have something close to the case where the $x_i$ are Gaussian?

Comment: I can do the Gaussian case because the exact pdf of $s_n$ can be obtained. The Berry-Esseen theorem is still about the tail. So if I let $\epsilon\to0$ in my case, the bound will still be quite loose.

Comment: But you have a bound for $|P(S_n/\sqrt n \in I)-P(N\in I)|$ for each interval $I$, don't you?